# (postgres) Selecionar várias colunas usando distinct em apenas uma coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Tenho uma query que traz todos os resultados de um banco de acordo com o id da pesquisa:

```sql
    select pic.* from pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma pi2
    join pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma_convite pic on pic.pesquisa_idioma_id = pi2.id
    where pi2.pesquisa_id = 2
    order by envio_id desc
```

Essa query traz um resultado semelhante a esse:

| id | pesquisa_idioma_id | envio_id | pesquisa_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 22 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 21 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 20 | 2 |

Como eu faria para selecionar todas as colunas, em que o valor de pesquisa_idioma_id seja distinto? O resultado esperado seria algo como:

| id | pesquisa_idioma_id | envio_id | pesquisa_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 22 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 21 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No PostgreSQL você pode usar [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pic.pesquisa_idioma_id) pic.*
FROM pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma pi2
JOIN pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma_convite pic ON pic.pesquisa_idioma_id = pi2.id
WHERE pi2.pesquisa_id = 2
ORDER BY pic.pesquisa_idioma_id, pic.envio_id DESC
```

---

Lembrando que `DISTINCT ON` é uma extensão do PostgreSQL. Uma forma mais genérica, para bancos que suportem CTE (Common Table Expressions), seria:

```sql
WITH dados AS (
  SELECT
    pic.id, pic.pesquisa_idioma_id, pic.envio_id, pic.pesquisa_id,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pic.pesquisa_idioma_id ORDER BY pic.envio_id DESC) AS rank
  FROM pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma pi2
  JOIN pesquisa.pesquisa_idioma_convite pic ON pic.pesquisa_idioma_id = pi2.id
  WHERE pi2.pesquisa_id = 2
)
SELECT dados.id, dados.pesquisa_idioma_id, dados.envio_id, dados.pesquisa_id
FROM dados
WHERE dados.rank = 1
ORDER BY dados.pesquisa_idioma_id
```

A ideia do `row_number` é colocar uma numeração automática, que vai sendo incrementada para cada registro que tem o mesmo `pesquisa_idioma_id` (pois é a coluna indicada no `PARTITION BY`). E como o `ORDER BY` indica que estou ordenando por `envio_id DESC`, o maior valor de `envio_id` para cada `pesquisa_idioma_id` terá sempre o valor igual a 1. Então no `SELECT` final eu pego somente os que tem este valor igual a 1.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelo conhecimento compartilhado.